# How to evaluate performance of (variational) autoencoders?

Tags: neural-networks, model-evaluation, validation, autoencoders

Let's assume that you have trained your (variational) autoencoder on MNIST digits. After some time, you check the result and decide that the reconstruction is pretty good. But this is highly subjective.

Imagine that you give the encoder a picture that show an 'X'. Looking at the output, the reconstruction should be really bad. But again, this is subjective.

I am looking for a way to objectively evaluate the performance for the current image. For VAE, the cost function during the training is a combination of a reconstruction error (MSE in my case) and the KL-divergence. Until now, I used the lone reconstruction error for this, as the dramatically rises when feeding an X.

The problem is: where do I draw a line between 'good' and 'bad' reconstructions and based on which objective measure can I do this?

Comment: This is the value of domain expertise.  If you understand your domain, you can put inputs that are good (in-bounds) and bad (vastly out of bounds) and allow the data to tell you the parameters of the line-of-discrimination (in the sense of discriminant), aka the healthy classifier division line.  You can feed in each of the letters of the [EMNIST](https://www.nist.gov/itl/products-and-services/emnist-dataset) alphabet to your digit-trained recognizer and consider things like "A", "I" and "O" as well as "X".   This should motivate multiple, complimentary, types of errors.  (L-inf, L2, L1, ...)

Comment: (Variational) Autoencoders can be used for many different tasks. VAEs, specifically, can be used for density estimation, anomaly detection, feature extraction, image generation, etc. A proper performance metric requires the definition of a task. What is the purpose of your model?